# Curve_fit fails on Exponentiated Weibull distribution

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting, weibull

I am trying to use

```
scipy.optimize.curve_fit(func,xdata,ydata)
```

To determine the parameters of **exponentiated weibull** distribution:

```
#define exponentiated weibull distribution
def expweib(x,k,lamda,alpha):
      return alpha*(k/lamda)*((x/lamda)**(k-1))*((1-np.exp(-(x/lamda)*k))**(alpha-1))*np.exp(-(x/lamda)*k)


 #First generate random sample of exponentiated weibull distribution using stats.exponweib.rvs
data = stats.exponweib.rvs(a = 1, c = 82.243021128368554, loc = 0,scale = 989.7422, size = 1000 )


#Then use the sample data to draw a histogram
entries_Test, bin_edges_Test, patches_Test = plt.hist(data, bins=50, range=[909.5,1010.5], normed=True)

#calculate bin middles of the histogram
bin_middles_Test = 0.5*(bin_edges_Test[1:] + bin_edges_Test[:-1])

#use bin_middles_Test as xdata, bin_edges_Test as ydata, previously defined expweib as func, call curve_fit method:
params, pcov = curve_fit(weib,bin_middles_Test, entries_Test )
```

Then the error occurs:

```
OptimizeWarning: Covariance of the parameters could not be estimatedcategory=OptimizeWarning)
```

I cannot identify which step has the issue, could anyone help?

Thank you

Comment: I guess `curve_fit(weib` should actually be `curve_fit(expweib`?!

Comment: Instead of fitting the PDF to the histogram, you could fit the distribution to the samples using the method `exponweib.fit`.  That method fits the distribution using maximum likelihood.

Answer (score 1):

Reading through documentation for **curve_fit** method here, https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html, for *method* argument, they have mentioned that `the default 'lm' method won't work if the number of observations is less than the number of variables, in which case you should use either of *'trf'* or *'dogbox'* method`.

Also, reading about *'pcov'* in Return values section, they have mentioned that the entries will be *inf* if `the Jacobian matrix at the solution does not have a full rank`.

I tried your code with both *trf* and *dogbox* and got pconv array full of zeros